# how to get more specific error information for view / template render errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, erb

All I get is a humungous stack trace which mostly has middleware and controller related stack trace as I can see, but is there a way in rails to know that at rendering which exact line for a view, layout or partial an error occurred?

for example,

```
F, [2017-09-03T11:27:10.616818 #4598] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1):
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template/error.rb:67:in `initialize'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:321:in `handle_render_error'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:160:in `rescue in render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:64:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
```

Would like to know which line of a template too. I am using the following gems currently

```
group :development do
    gem 'meta_request'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  # gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.5', :require => false
  gem 'page-object', '~> 2.1.1'
  gem 'watir', '~> 6.3'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.6.1'
  # Fixtures are messy!
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.8'
  gem 'ffaker', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'json-schema', '~> 2.8'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.9.1'
end
```

So I do get an idea of what template it broke, but the cryptic error message isn't helpful at all in any further details.

Comment: can you upload the controller that deals with this view

Comment: If you check the server logs you will see the entire log and you should be able to trace back to the file causing the error

Comment: Here's the gist to the entire log on console https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/d99666c3d2bd365380bb930eba53b946, it doesn't mention which template file

Answer (score 0):

From the error log you posted in the comments, it looks like the only offending line in your code is in `app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:in new` (from like 34 of the error code you posted)